# Rails - how do I validate existence of a row referenced by foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, foreign-keys

Given that the "Rails Way" seems to be not to use foreign key constraints, I'm looking for an alternative that will allow me to validate that the row a foreign key references does in fact exist in TableA before I save an object in TableB with table_a_id.

The only resource I've found to do this so far (can't find a link to the blog post it was mentioned in, was dated 2007) doesn't appear to be compatible with Rails 3.2, so can anyone suggest a way of doing this?

I'm currently looking at creating a validator to manually assign to the relevant attributes in my models, but I can't work out how to do it with validate_each(object, attribute, value).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a plugin that helps you with this for **belongs_to** associations: [Validates existence of](https://github.com/perfectline/validates_existence). But, maybe you can add your own validation?  What about something like this:

```
# Assuming your foreign key is user_id (which references the table User)
validate :user_id_exists

def user_id_exists
  return false if User.find_by_id(self.user_id).nil?
end
```

Comment: I have ~20 models I want to use this in, so for the purpose of DRY, I'm really after a validator instead of rolling a custom validation method for every foreign key. That plugin looks perfect for that, I'll give it a go now, thanks =]

Comment: This does not work. As @DjAlan points out, `User.find` will throw. It does not return nil if the record is not found.

Comment: All you need to do is change it to User.find_by_id

Comment: I had to solve a similar problem and created a gem called [foreign_key_validation](https://github.com/marcusg/foreign_key_validation). Hope this helps!

Comment: Short version: `def user_id_exists; User.exists?(self.user_id); end`

Answer (score 37):

Simply use like below,

```
validates :user, presence: true
```

It will automatically check the existence of user record in db.

Reference from the [Active Record Validation - `presence`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence):

> If you want to be sure that an association is present, you'll need to
>   test whether the associated object itself is present, and not the
>   foreign key used to map the association. This way, it is not only
>   checked that the foreign key is not empty but also that the referenced
>   object exists.

Comment: remember `belongs_to :user` has to be present for this to work.

Comment: If the models are called TableB and TableA, then I guess what you want is something like: `class TableB < ActiveRecord::Base;  belongs_to :table_a;  validates :table_a, presence: true;  ...`

Comment: I think that this is not the answer to the question. The question says how can you check that the object exists in the database and it's not a fake _id. `Validates presence` checks that the id is always present

Comment: @ignaciochiazzo It is the answer to the question. Indeed, the `presence` validator normally uses the `blank?` method to check if the value is either `nil` or a blank string. But also, when the attribute is a foreign key, and `belongs_to` is present, it slightly changes its behaviour to also check that the referenced object exists in the database. I suggested an edit to the answer to reference the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

I had problems with this piece of code:

```
return false if User.find(self.user_id).nil?
```

I had to catch the ActiveRecord exception when no matching record was found. *nil?* does not work when no record is found; the exception is thrown before *nil?* is executed.

```
# Assuming your foreign key is user_id (which references the table User)
validate :user_id_exists

def user_id_exists
  begin
    User.find(self.user_id)
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    errors.add(:user_id, "user_id foreign key must exist")
    false
  end
end
```

This is useful when you use *invalid?* assertions in unit tests.

```
request.user_id = unknown
assert request.invalid?

request.user_id = 1
assert request.valid?
```

Comment: All you need to do is change it to User.find_by_id

Comment: Why rely on an exception? That doesn't really make it exceptional.

Answer (score 3):

Note that as of Rails 3.2, the validates_presence_of works exactly the way you want it to in this case and you don't have to build a complicated structure like the above answers or even use the nice validates_existence_of gem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the `inverse_of` option and validate that it's presence is true.

From the [Active Record Validations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validation-helpers):

> In order to validate associated records whose presence is required,
>   you must specify the **:inverse_of** option for the association

Answer (score 1):

I dislike exceptions. I solved this problem by doing this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

    validate :bar_exists

    protected

    def bar_exists
        if !User.where(bar_id: self.bar_id).exists? then
            errors.add(:bar_id, 'A valid bar_id is valid.')
        end
    end

end
```